# Combining Formatting and Databinding from the database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, string-formatting, datarepeater

I have a set of labels in a DataRepeater. The labels get their values from a table in a SQL database (Let say GetSQLResults gets the data from SQL database and returns a DataTable).

```
Dim salesDataTable As DataTable = GetSQLResults()
```

And for the binding

```
SalesLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", salesDataTable , "Sales")
```

Where SalesLabel is a label in the form and "Sales" is the name of the column in the database.

What I want to do is to apply let say US money formatting to this Sales value that comes from the database. I don't know how to combine formatting information with the command that I wrote above for DataBinding. It is a Windows Form application and I am using VB .Net. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Binding` class has a [`FormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formatstring.aspx) property which you should be able to feed the standard or custom [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx) you desire.

I think perhaps something like:

```
Dim salesBinding As Binding = new Binding("Text", salesDataTable , "Sales")
salesBinding.FormatString = "C"
SalesLabel.DataBindings.Add(salesBinding)
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: Hi nkvu! Thanks for your response. What you suggested made all the sense to me but did not work for me.  Though it led me to find the following solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this based on nkvu answer and a post at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c860168f-46e5-4786-a68d-ac69c6a7a248/

```
Dim WithEvents salesBinding As Binding
```

---

```
salesBinding = New Binding("Text", salesDataTable , "Sales")
SalesLabel.DataBindings.Add(salesBinding)
```

---

```
Private Sub salesBinding_Format(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs) Handles salesBinding .Format
    If e.Value Is DBNull.Value Then
    Else
        e.Value = Format(e.Value, "c")
    End If
End Sub
```

This did the trick for me.